# How to authorize my VPS to use my Gmail account?

Tags: java, gmail

I have a Java server (WAR) that I develop and I want to add a "contact us" rest API where it will use my gmail account to send the email to me (my gmail account). On my local computer it works and now I want to deploy the war to my vps (ubuntu).

I need to authorize it to use my Gmail account, otherwise I will get a suspicious sign in that was blocked.

How can I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the Gmail API is probably the preferred solution https://developers.google.com/gmail/api

But as a quick alternative:

The typical VPS running Linux has a SMTP server installed that allows you to send mail with either

- “the sendmail” (compatible) command `/usr/lib/sendmail`
- an smtp server that listens on localhost port 25

Reliable mail delivery using your own @example.com domain takes some more effort but your “contact us “ messages have only you yourself as te recipient and if they end up in a spam folder simply white list your app

Comment: Thanks. While I read more about the API, I want to add that I use javax.mail and it works perfectly locally so no real effort here except for "whitelisting" my vps which I don't know how.